# Error the condition has length > 1 when if_else doesn't solve the issue

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm trying to do some code analysis with R and I face an issue. Indeed, I use the 'population data' and I want to order my countries according to their region (Oceania, Asia, Europe... and so on). For this purpose, I need to use a condition structure in order to check if a country is in a certain region or not. Nonetheless, I don't manage to do this for several regions (more than two).

I tried, as first solution, to do some condition structure with if, else if, else :

```
if(population_df$country %in% europe_countries) {
  population_df$region <- "Europe"
}
else if(population_df$country %in% africa_countries) {
  population_df$region <- "Africa"
}
else if(population_df$country %in% america_countries) {
  population_df$region <- "America"
}
else if(population_df$country %in% oceania_countries) {
  population_df$region <- "Oceania"
}
else if(population_df$country %in% asia_countries) {
  population_df$region <- "Asia"
}
```

But it doesn't work because the console loads an error as :

> Error in if (population_df$country %in% europe_countries) { :
> the condition has length > 1

By searching on web pages, I understood this error because I can't use vectors in if structure (I don't understand really why but it's a fact).

I tried a second solution with some if_else structures :

```
population_df$region <- if_else(population_df$country %in% europe_countries, "Europe", "")
population_df$region <- if_else(population_df$country %in% africa_countries, "Africa", "")
```

But as expected, it doesn't work because if I have an European country, my second if_else will replace "Europe" by "".

I don't have any other idea to make my script working, so if anybody of you would have an idea, it would be a pleasure.

Here my complete code :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

View(population)

spe_countries <- c("Nigeria", "Egypt", "Ethiopia", "France", "Germany", "Spain", "United States of America",
                   "Canada", "Mexico", "Australia", "New Zealand", "China", "Japan", "India")

europe_countries <- c("France", "Germany", "Spain")
africa_countries <- c("Nigeria", "Egypt", "Ethiopia")
america_countries <- c("United States of America","Canada", "Mexico")
oceania_countries <- c("Australia", "New Zealand")
asia_countries <- c("China", "Japan", "India")

population_df <- population %>%
  filter(country %in% spe_countries)

View(population_df)

if(population_df$country %in% europe_countries) {
  population_df$region <- "Europe"
}
else if(population_df$country %in% africa_countries) {
  population_df$region <- "Africa"
}
else if(population_df$country %in% america_countries) {
  population_df$region <- "America"
}
else if(population_df$country %in% oceania_countries) {
  population_df$region <- "Oceania"
}
else if(population_df$country %in% asia_countries) {
  population_df$region <- "Asia"
}

population_df$region <- if_else(population_df$country %in% europe_countries, "Europe", "")
population_df$region <- if_else(population_df$country %in% africa_countries, "Africa", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Package `countrycode` has a data frame called codelist_panel that has information about countries, including their respective continent.

By `left_join`ing the your df with the codelist_panel (only the columns country and continent) it automatically matches the continents with the correct country.

```
library(tidyverse)

population %>%
  left_join(
    .,
    countrycode::codelist_panel %>%
      select(1, 5) %>%
      distinct(country = country.name.en, continent)
  )

Joining, by = "country"
# A tibble: 4,060 × 4
   country      year population continent
   <chr>       <int>      <int> <chr>    
 1 Afghanistan  1995   17586073 Asia     
 2 Afghanistan  1996   18415307 Asia     
 3 Afghanistan  1997   19021226 Asia     
 4 Afghanistan  1998   19496836 Asia     
 5 Afghanistan  1999   19987071 Asia     
 6 Afghanistan  2000   20595360 Asia     
 7 Afghanistan  2001   21347782 Asia     
 8 Afghanistan  2002   22202806 Asia     
 9 Afghanistan  2003   23116142 Asia     
10 Afghanistan  2004   24018682 Asia     
# … with 4,050 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, I don't really understand your code. Could you please explain it a little bit for me? Sorry but I start with R

Comment: I explained a little bit - but look up the functions left_join and the read up on the package countrycode for better understanding

Comment: Okay thanks for the tips and your help. But I searched help for the general case and not specifically for countries, so it doesn't work. I just wanted to understand how to do if I'm in a similar situation. Maybe, I didn't detail my post enough, sorry

Comment: @NoCodeGamer Literally not stated in the question that you want a general solution, if so explain how. Provide proper context, sample data and expected output next time